# How to make rounded corner progress bar in swift?

Tags: swift

Here I Have tried to make Rounded Rect corner progress bar but I have some problem to create it, here I have post my code what I am tried?

Any one Give idea to customize the progress bar to rounded rect corner progress bar.

```
self.progressView.frame=CGRectMake(55, 490, 200, 15)
self.progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
self.progressView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 7.0)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Although you have set the corner radius, you also need to tell the view not to draw anything outside of the view's bounds by setting

```
self.progressView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: No i don't need to, i answered it! @saravanakumar needs to click it lol

Comment: Hi Swinny89 but it is not implement in ios 9 and iphone 6, why ?

Answer (score 20):

And if you want to have rounded edges for the inner bar too, you can also add this code:

```
// Set the rounded edge for the outer bar
self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
self.clipsToBounds = true

// Set the rounded edge for the inner bar        
self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 12
self.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 5):

In which it tells you to set the corner radius and then clip to bounds: (The sublayers is so the inside bar has rounded corners as well.)
soo add these lines 
because you need to set both the progress color and his layer also...

```
 progressBar.layer.cornerRadius = 8
 progressBar.clipsToBounds = true
 progressBar.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 8
 progressBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0**

```
//Extension to set corner any view  set border width and color. 
extension UIView{
    func setCorner(withRadius:Int, borderWidth:Int = 0, color: UIColor = .clear){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.borderColor = color
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

use it as

```
self.progressView.setCorner(withRadius: 12)
```

Comment: clipsToBounds!!! gotta remember that. Tx!

Answer (score 1):

UIProgressView changed position of UIImageView which show current value of progress bar. I have small update to fix this issue

```
 self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
 self.clipsToBounds = true
 for subview in subviews {
    if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView {
       imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
       imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an other way to make the change global and update the corner radius from the storyboard. you can add this as an extension to the UIProgressView
Note: Make sure that you set your custom height is set by constraints

```
extension UIProgressView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    
    get {
        self.cornerRadius
    }
    
    set {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = newValue
        self.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
    }
  }
}
```