# How to smoothly round the corners of a progress bar when the height is increased?

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, cornerradius

I am trying to make a progress bar like this:

[image]

I used this SO post to learn how to round corners: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114779/how-to-make-rounded-corner-progress-bar-in-swift/32114876)

Which works great when your progress bar height doesn't go past 6. When I make my progress bar bigger using:

```
        progressBar.transform = progressBar.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 8)
```

The result it: [image]

It doesn't matter what the corner radius value is set to, it's not round. I am aware that making the corner radius value larger than the height can result in straight line corners but it doesn't matter what I set the corner radius to (I can set it to 1/2/4 and get similar results), the corners won't round.

Here is my code:

```
 progressBar.transform = progressBar.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 8)
 progressBar.layer.cornerRadius = 8
 progressBar.clipsToBounds = true
 progressBar.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 8
 progressBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
```

(Corner radius and the y value are the same because the y is multiplied by 2)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out while writing this. You use corner radius like I have in the post above:

```
progressBar.layer.cornerRadius = 8
progressBar.clipsToBounds = true
progressBar.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 8
progressBar.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
```

To increase the size you set a height constraint on the progress bar:
[image]